# Angular ng-table not able to default sort on variable value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am  trying to sort a table using angularjs ng-table, however i am not able to do that. Below is the code which i am using for sorting.

```
var sortKey = $scope.fieldName;  
$scope.releasedTable = new ngTableParams({  
    page : 1,  
    count : $scope.defaultpageSize,  
    sorting : {  
        sortKey : 'desc'  
    }  
});
```

If I am passing the dynamically variable such as sortKey above it is not working. However my below code works because of static variable fName in it.

```
$scope.releasedTable = new ngTableParams({  
    page : 1,  
    count : $scope.defaultpageSize,  
    sorting : {  
        fName : 'desc'  
    }  
});
```

html :

```
 <table  id="action-pending-table" ng-table="releasedTable" class="table table-striped">  
              <thead>  
               <tr>  
               <th ng-repeat="column in columns"  
  ng-class="{'sort-asc': releasedTable.isSortBy(column.fieldName, 'asc'),  
  'sort-desc': releasedTable.isSortBy(column.fieldName, 'desc')}"  
 ng-click="releasedTable.sorting(column.fieldName,   releasedTable.isSortBy(column.fieldName, 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc');   changeIcon(icon)"  ng-if="column.display"> {{column.displayName}}
 <icon-change icon="icon"></icon-change></th>  
                    </tr>  
                </thead> 

                <tbody>    
                    <tr ng-repeat="record in records">    
                        <td ng-repeat="column in columns">    
<span ng-if="isNeededLink(column.fieldName)">>{{record[column.fieldName]}}  </span></td>
                    </tr>  
                </tbody>  
            </table>
```

Please suggest how can I resolve this.

Comment: can you show me the html ?

Comment: @NadeemKhoury Have added in question please check

Comment: try [sortKey] = 'desc'

Comment: @EkanshRastogi Thanks a lot its working, but giving javascript syntax error on aptana studio 3. Btw can you please explain how this  is working here,

Comment: if you try to access a field via a variable this is a syntax. e.g array[0].id can also be accessed by var field='id', array[0][field] = 'something'